# How to retrieve all array values stored in local storage

Tags: html, local-storage

I have stored an array in local storage. When I access all the values in the same function I get all the values but when I try to access them outside the function I get only the last pushed value. How do I retrieve all the values outside the function?

```
storeGrabID(10);
storeGrabID(7);
storeGrabID(9);
storeGrabID(4);
//storing function
function storeGrabID(id)
{
    var list = new Array(); 
    list.push(id);
    localStorage.setItem('offerID',JSON.stringify(list));
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('offerID'));//getting all the values
}
console.log(localStorage.getItem('offerID'));//getting the last pushed value i.e. 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's normal because each time you called storeGrabID you create another list new array where you add the element passed in parameter.

In each time you stored only one element (the last) and in the function you stored in the local storage this element.

Two solution to solve your issue : 
1) get your array from the Local storage each time you called your function *
advantage : run safe 
inconvinient can't display what you have in your array without load it from your local storage

```
storeGrabID(10);
storeGrabID(7);
storeGrabID(9);
storeGrabID(4);
//storing function
function storeGrabID(id)
{
    var list = localStorage.getItem('offerID');
    list.push(id);
    localStorage.setItem('offerID',JSON.stringify(list));
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('offerID'));//getting all the values
}
```

2) one other way but less proper is to put your list outside your array
advantage : fast to implement 
inconvinient : not really proper (global variable)

```
var list = new Array(); 
storeGrabID(10);
storeGrabID(7);
storeGrabID(9);
storeGrabID(4);
//storing function
function storeGrabID(id)
{
    list.push(id);
    localStorage.setItem('offerID',JSON.stringify(list));
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('offerID'));//getting all the values
}
console.log(localStorage.getItem('offerID'));//getting the last pushed value i.e
```